# Group by Customer And Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I want to list last payments of my customers order by date descending.

I wrote a sql query

```
 SELECT CARHARTAR,
       CARHARREFNO,
       CARHARCARKOD,
       CARHARCARUNVAN,
       CARHARACIKLAMA,
       CARHARTUTAR
FROM   CARHAR
WHERE  ( CARHARTIPI IN ( 2, 4 ) )
       AND ( CARHARISTIPNO IN ( 2, 6 ) )
       AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'W%' )
       AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'Z%' )
       AND ( CARHARGCFLAG = 2 )
       AND ( CARHARIADEFLAG = 0 )
ORDER  BY CARHARTAR DESC
```

This query list all payments order by date descending. But i only need last payment. I'm using group by carharcarkod but i have an aggreate function problem. What should i do ?

[Here is a screenshot of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG7tj.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using? Which columns constitute  primary key?

Comment: Which payment you want to show if customer has paid twice in the same day?

Comment: i'm using sql server 2005. And there is no primary key in table. And we're wholesale company that's why our customers don't pay twice in one day.

Comment: if there exist a payment twice in one day i can sum it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `ROW_NUMBER` function would do what you are after:

```
;WITH Payments AS
(   SELECT  CARHARTAR,
            CARHARREFNO,
            CARHARCARKOD,
            CARHARCARUNVAN,
            CARHARACIKLAMA,
            CARHARTUTAR,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CARHARCARKOD ORDER BY CARHARTAR DESC) [RowNumber]
    FROM    CARHAR
    WHERE   CARHARTIPI IN (2, 4)
    AND     CARHARISTIPNO IN (2, 6)
    AND     CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'W%'
    AND     CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'Z%'
    AND     CARHARGCFLAG = 2
    AND     CARHARIADEFLAG = 0
)
SELECT  CARHARTAR,
        CARHARREFNO,
        CARHARCARKOD,
        CARHARCARUNVAN,
        CARHARACIKLAMA,
        CARHARTUTAR
FROM    Payments
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY CARHARTAR
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use group by clause then you must include all fields in group by which you want to select.

```
SELECT CARHARTAR,
   CARHARCARKOD FROM   CARHAR WHERE  ( CARHARTIPI IN ( 2, 4 ) )
   AND ( CARHARISTIPNO IN ( 2, 6 ) )
   AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'W%' )
   AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'Z%' )
   AND ( CARHARGCFLAG = 2 )
   AND ( CARHARIADEFLAG = 0 ) GROUP BY CARHARTAR,carharcarkod DESC
```

Comment: i know group by usage. But i need all fields (CARHARTAR,
       CARHARREFNO,
       CARHARCARKOD,
       CARHARCARUNVAN,
       CARHARACIKLAMA,
       CARHARTUTAR) and i don't know what should i do

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
SELECT CARHARCARKOD,max(CARHARTAR) [CARHARTAR]
FROM   CARHAR
WHERE  ( CARHARTIPI IN ( 2, 4 ) )
       AND ( CARHARISTIPNO IN ( 2, 6 ) )
       AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'W%' )
       AND ( CARHARCARKOD NOT LIKE 'Z%' )
       AND ( CARHARGCFLAG = 2 )
       AND ( CARHARIADEFLAG = 0 )
group by CARHARCARKOD    )   
select C.CARHARTAR,
       C.CARHARREFNO,
       C.CARHARCARKOD,
       C.CARHARCARUNVAN,
       C.CARHARACIKLAMA,
       C.CARHARTUTAR
FROM  cte join CARHAR C
on  CTE.CARHARCARKOD =C.CARHARCARKOD     
and cte.CARHARTAR= C.CARHARTAR
```

Comment: thank you for helping. But the query result is not correct. You can see here : http://www.flickr.com/photos/cihankusmez/7582490650/

Comment: i need only last payments of customers